# I can't use the System.Runtime 4.3.0 in a .net 4.7 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a .net 4.7 project which has installed the version 4.3.0 of System.Runtime. But when I run the project I get an exception that say that it can't be found the version 4.1.0.0.

If I go to the nuget manager, I install the version 4.1.0.0 in the project, then it works. So I have tried to update again to the version 4.3.0, but again, I get the problem.

The project was working until now, really I don't know why it stops to work because I don't touch anything related with the nuget packages.

Also I have tried to created a new empty solution and add the project, to try a fresh solution, but the problem is the same.

How could I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the configuration file of the project for any package related dependency!

Comment: maybe a binding redirect is required? You could try reproduce it in a new project and share it on github

Comment: is it a packages.config based project or using the new PackageReference style nuget package management in vs 2017 15.2?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have a package.config file where is set the version of the dll that it should use. How I could use the new PackageReference style?

Comment: http://blog.nuget.org/images/2017-03-16-NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild/trypackageref.gif
But that's not the problem here. Did you install the dependencies using system.runtime before installing system.runtime? Are there any binding redirects in the app.config file (/ .config file in build output)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet should generate the necessary binding redirects into the `App.config` for `packages.config` based projects or set `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` to `true` for csproj files using `PackageReference` to reference NuGet packages.

If for some reason this did not happen or you are using the libraries from a different project / application, it may be necessary to add the binding redirect manually to the `app.config` / `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have tried to create an empty solution and create the projects to, and copy all the .cs and rest of the files to this new projects. I have install again the nuget packges that I need but the problem is the same. I have a .net 4.7 application and an the assembly that I am trying to test is a .net standar 1.6. When I run a method from a class of the .net standard I get the error. The error is with linq, I select the version 4.1.0.0 that is the requested, instead of the actual version 4.3.0, but the problem is the same. I don't have the app.config.

Comment: Now I have all my projects as .net 4.7 and still in the test project I have to use the version 4.1.0 instead of 4.3.0. But I don't know where to see or how to set that I want to use the last version. Perhaps could it be that the main assembly use the 4.1.0? But I created a new project .net 4.7 and just copy the .cs files, no the configuration files, so I don't know why it should use the version 4.1.0.

Comment: What kind of projects are you using? can you upload a repro somewhere? does adding the binding redirect manually to a new app.config fix the issue?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía I am facing similar issue with projects Net462 and Net472, as soon as I add a nuget package. Have you got any solution for this?